# ESXi boot stuck at "Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh"

Tags: vmware-esxi, uefi

I had to move the primary hard drive that has ESXi installed to the next slot over due to a broken pin on the connector. This causes the system to boot to the screen which says "Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh, or any other key to continue". I run mount -r then type exit and ESXi is able to boot up. My question is how can I tell EFI to use that drive to boot in case I loose power or have to remotely reboot machine and can't intervene to type those commands. I am not familiar with the process so would prefer expert advice rather than risking the machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix it in UEFI configuration of your server, because this doesn't seem to be an ESXi related error.

If you have dual bios on your motherboard, turn off the server, switch to the backup bios and check out how it does. It should boot. If it does, check out your server's or motherboard's docs to find out how to Load UEFI defaults.

You didn't provide enough informations for us to help you further, such as hardware brand/model/version, software versions, etc.